# How to write new line with drawText() in magento?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, newline, magento-1.9

I am trying to put a new line with the Magento function `drawText();` I was trying the code below but it showing all statement like `Line 1! \n Line 1!`

Can anyone tell me how I can print multiple new lines using the following code.

```
 $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Line 1! \n Line 1!'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a separate call to $page->drawText for each line, as per this - [PHP + PDF Line Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950654/php-pdf-line-break)

```
 $textChunk = wordwrap($value, 20, "\n");
 foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
   if ($value!=='') {
     $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
     $line -=14;
   }
 }
```